# InstallShield .NET 4.6.1 Framework installation on Windows 8

Tags: .net, installation, installshield, windows-installer

I'm trying to install .NET Framework 4.6.1 using its extracted msi file(netfx_Full_x64.msi) from NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe on Windows 8.  This is needed because we're packaging this within another msi package using InstallShield.  It works fine with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.
When I try to install it with Windows 8, I get the following error:
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system but is currently turned off. To enable the .NET Framework 4.5, use Turn Windows features on or off in Control Panel.

1. I checked the Windows feature and it's turn on.
2. Not sure why it's asking for this when I'm trying to install a later version of .NET Framework.
3. I tried running the .NET Framework executable in silent in the UI phase of the MSI installation but I was getting an error: WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus

Anyone has experience with this and can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not had experience with this but based on the error, the installer for .NET Framework for Windows 8 and possibly newer, requires enabling the .NET Framework 4.5 first. On windows 8 .NET Framework is listed as a feature but the bits that install it are not present locally. You need to make sure that the .NET framework for Windows 8 is enabled.

Depending on the version of InstallShield, you may be able to add the .NET framework to a feature (for MSI) or for a suite/advanced UI install, associate it to a Package that will install. Be sure to sequence this before the required .NET Framework 4.6 install.

Otherwise you will need to create a custom prerequisite that calls DISM to install the package.

If you are targeting systems that are offline, without any access to the Internet, then you will need to prompt the user to Install .NET Framework 4.5 before installing and then exit the installer. This is because with Windows 8 the bits are not local and it will attempt to download them. If there isn't an internet connection then the OS needs access to the original installation media which goes beyond the scope of most installers.

---

EDIT: I read your description again and you state that you have verified that the feature for .NET Framework 4.5 is enabled. At that point I would be just as confused as you. Have you checked the state of the feature using a CMD prompt or PowerShell? 
Try the following command

```
DISM.exe /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:NetFx3
DISM.exe /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:NetFx4-AdvSrvs
DISM.exe /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
```

Check the current version and the state of each package. The ironic thing is that on Windows 10 (where I did a sanity check for this ) It shows that 4.6 is installed but still shows a major/minor of 4.5. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

> - On Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, it's listed as Update for
>     Microsoft Windows (KB3102439) under the Installed Updates item in
>     Control Panel.
> - On Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, it's listed as Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102467) under the Installed Updates item in
>     Control Panel.
> - On Windows 10, it's listed as Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102495) under the Installed Updates item in Control Panel.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102436

you'll have to validate it via a launch condition. you can do that via this registry key :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
```

the value `Version` should be greater than `4.6.01055`

the message could ask your user to update it's setup with the specific KB